# How to get to Christmas Island?

Tags: australia, islands, sea-travel, christmas-island

[Christmas Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Island) is an island of Australia far off the northwest of the mainland, much closer to Indonesia.

[image: Where is Christmas Island?]
<sup>(Thanks to Wikimedia Commons for the map)</sup>

I know I can fly there but [Wikitravel seems to suggest there's no regular ferry or boat transport](http://wikitravel.org/en/Christmas_Island#By_boat).

It does mention that I might be able to get there by private yacht or by cruise ship. Does anybody have some actual information about how to find either of these and how much it might cost?

I'd like to know both about getting there (or back) from Australia and from Indonesia. Would one be easier than the other? Would customs and immigrations rules make the latter too tricky? Would it be a good way to get from Australia to Southeast Asia overland?

Comment: Your timing is a bit off -- there's a few days left still.

Comment: I hope you will utilize those few days to find me a berth to get there in time!

Comment: The most impressive time to visit Christmas Island is during the migration of [red crabs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Island_red_crab).

Comment: I wonder if they do in fact do anything special for Christmas and if there's any influx of tourists at that time?

Comment: I assume that like [San Pedro prison](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/how-can-you-get-into-the-san-pedro-prison-in-la-paz-and-out-again), you want to be able to leave as well. [Christmas_Island#Refugee_and_immigration_detention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Island#Refugee_and_immigration_detention). Without wanting to comment on mandatory detention, it's sad when an island becomes mainly known for its detention centre.

Comment: Step 1) Get to Java in Indonesia.  Step 2) Hop on a "people smuggling boat", one of these leaves every couple of days if not more frequently.  Step 3) Christmas Island!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, there is no private yacht or cruise from Indonesia to Christmas Island.

On the other hand, there is a cruise from Fremantle, Australia to the islands.
The boat's name is Athena (from a company called Classic International Course) and here is the [Athena's schedules](http://www.christmas.net.au/getting-here/cruising.html).

The price varies from USD 2000-2800 for the cheapest cabin (for 2 adults per room) and the details can be found in the [company website](http://www.onlinecruises.com.au/CruisesList.aspx?isTop=1).

Answer (score 6):

You could use [find-a-crew.net](http://find-a-crew.net) I read the [blog of a kiwi girl](http://www.bugbitten.com/blogs/Worldwide/kyles/Across_the_waterIndo_to_AUSTRALIA.html) who was cycling from London to NZ she used the site to finally get a lift from Indonesia to to Australia albeit via Thursday island and not Christmas Island, Could still be useful though.